# Warning while declaring versions of dependencies in POM

Tags: maven

When I specify version of my dependencies within pom.xml, there's a warning :

```
Overrides version defined in PluginManagement. The managed version is _____.
```

What does this mean and how do I rectify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message would mean that the version you have specified for a plugin is different than the version "recommended" by the parent (has nothing to do with deps). You are allowed to do this.

[Plugin Management](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

Comment: but where/who is the parent, I haven't specified any POM or project as parent !?

Comment: That depends on the Maven version. Please see the Super Pom section on this page for a description: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html